# Why was my question asking whether I should point out flaws on a potential employer's website off-topic?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Yesterday I posted [Pointing out flaws in their website?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96297/63121), and it was put on hold as being "primarily opinion based".

Having been active on other SE sites I thought I had an understanding of what "primarily opinion based" meant, but it appears to be different on Workplace.SE. I have read through other questions posted on Workplace.SE and they could be primarily opinion based as well - in my opinion.

Examples:

1. [Should I decline a gift from my boss (the new owner of the company)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96335/63121)
2. [Is it obligatory to make small talk with your colleagues?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96084/63121)
3. [Completely burnt out at work but not sure how to continue](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/95896/63121)

All the questions above could be considered primarily opinion based as it is opinion-based on how the OPs should act.

Comment: No idea why it was considered off-topic. In general, I think folks tend to be too quick to vote to close questions. (FWIW, your question seems to be a duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/25861/should-i-inform-my-potential-employer-about-a-bug-in-their-application ), don't you think?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Did not know that question was there. But closed as dupe makes much more sense. Although the answers to that question differ from the ones to mine....

Comment: Voting to reopen

Comment: @RichardU thanks but it'll be closed as dupe since Joe pointed out an identical question.

Comment: @MichaelC. but if it is, it will be closed for the right reason.

Comment: @RichardU What if the other one is "primarily opinion-based"? Making both primarily opinion based. I ask because the answers to both are different.

Comment: Pointing out other broken windows, is not a good strategy for preventing your broken window from being fixed.  That said I think your question is good on its merits, which is what you should have argued here.

Comment: @MichaelC FWIW, that burnout question was already closed once, and then it got reopened. I personally don't agree that it should have been reopened, but my opinion is of miniscule importance if the community thinks otherwise. That aside, if the other question should also be closed, the community will do so. A lot of these close/reopen votes are subjective, due to the nature of the site. One question being closed and the other being open just means that the set of users who saw each question had different thresholds for "opinion-based".